# How are machines identified over the network?

Tags: networking, macos

I've been playing an online game and having challenged the developer I got IP banned. By using a VPN I bypassed it - after a while i couldn't log into my account anymore (only as a guest). The developer let me know that it was a machine ban (a term he coined himself) where he somehow knew it was my machine (MacOSX version 10.12.6) connecting to his game server. The game ban is completely server-sided. I changed my MAC address via terminal (even though this is dropped from packets due to security reasons), cleared my cache and yet I can't connect. Also, when I login as a guest a number 194xyz appears as the username, incrementing by 1 every time I login, whether I use the VPN or not. The developer also let me know that it was pretty simple and dumb - if that helps!

How is he figuring out that it is my computer and effectively blocking it? Any help would be appreciated!

**Update - Issue Resolved**

The developer was using a string known as a User-Agent that appears in the request headers of data being sent to and fro two sockets on the web. I identified this by using Mozilla Firefox's network panel in inspect element.

Comment: “How is he figuring out that it is my computer and effectively blocking it” - There are any number of ways (over a dozen) which can be used to uniquely identify your machine.  If your still using the vpn they likely banned that address as well

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified the online game, and that could make a lot of difference. A non-exclusive list of possibilities include

- If the game requires a download, there could well be a unique key which is sent as part of login/authentication.
- If the game is purely web based, it is quite likely it set a cookie - Cookies would persist across IP's, and are different to the cache.
- It is somewhat unlikely, but he could be doing some kind of client fingerprinting.  Computers can be surprisingly unique (even excluding IP addresses).  Have a look at [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) to get a good feel for how unique your system is.

Note that unless the game is on your computer and checking it, changing your MAC address will make absolutely no difference - that information is not sent through the Internet - and also there is no real reason for a game to check your MAC address - there are better ways of uniquely identifying a system.

**Update**

After looking at the site, I see it is in Flash.  I expect that there are FLASH cookies (rather then browser ones) which are being used to track you across sessions.  I don't do Windows or Flash, but [these can apparently be deleted in Flash Player](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-adobe-flash-cookies).

Comment: Similar to a web based cookie, installed software could generate a unique ID during install and send that during log in. I can only see developers bothering with this in competitive online games where people might get banned and then try to get around the ban.

Comment: @siradelaide - actually this is pretty trivial to do, and there are lots of usage cases, including advert targeting.

Comment: @davidgo - The game makes absolutely no downloads, I blocked it form setting cookies back when I could still connect and cleared the cache. As of the VPN, it connects through a unique IP every time I turn it on, so it couldn't have been banned. At this point theres only hope in figuring out what unique info is being sent to the server and spoof it. This is the game link (if this helps at all): https://pr3.goldtreeservers.net

Comment: See my updated answer - I expect the tracking mechanism is FLASH Cookies as opposed to browser cookies.

Comment: @davidgo I suspected it wouldn't work as the developer stated it's a machine ban, and after deleting the flash cookies that was confirmed. I still cannot connect.